# Using the charter font, F followed by a full stop looks like an E. What should I do?

Tags: kerning

Here is a screenshot of my document:

[image]

On the second line, there is an instance of "CNF." which totally looks like "CNE" to me (because the dot takes the place of the serif on the feet of an E).

I'm using the `charter` package and font. What should I do to bring the period a little bit further from the F?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
\noindent
This clausification follows from a straightforward conversion of the formula $(s \leftrightarrow x \oplus y \oplus c_{in}) \land (c_{out} \leftrightarrow ((x \oplus y) \land c_{in}) \lor (x \land y))$ to CNF. We see that we need $32$ extra variables and $32 \times 14 = 448$ clauses to encode a $32$-bit adder circuit using this method. This is almost certainly better than the circuit encoding, which requires both more variables and more clauses.
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: About the formula, I know...

Comment: Try `CNF\,.` That gives you a small space between F and the dot.

Comment: If you're sure you won't ever want to change the font, or that you won't ever want to copy and paste `F\,.` into another file...

Comment: That's really odd... On my system (Win7-64 bit, MikTeX 2.9, TeXMaker) everything looks fine, the period is placed properly, clearly after the `F`.

Comment: I can verify @CountZero's results too

Comment: I'm using pdfTeX Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian). Could it be a problem with the PDF viewer?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as @CountZero as well. Mac OS 10.7, MacTeX 2011 and `pdflatex`.

Comment: Maybe you somehow have an old version of the charter fonts? I see some notes about improving the kerning [at CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign/).

Comment: Oops, by bad. I forgot to include `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` in the MWE. Sorry :-/ Can you reproduce it now?

Comment: @Vegard: That's right, that does the trick! `:)`

Comment: @Vegard yes, I can confirm the problem now as well.

Comment: I think `\;` would produce a bit large a space, but you can try `CNF\kern0.075pt.` as a quick fix...

Comment: If you switch the two lines `\usepackage{charter}` and `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}`, the problem goes away. Not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with the `mathdesign` package. If you re-load the Charter font after `mathdesign` has already loaded the kerning will be correct:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{charter}

\begin{document}
\noindent
This clausification follows from a straightforward conversion of the formula $(s \leftrightarrow x \oplus y \oplus c_{in}) \land (c_{out} \leftrightarrow ((x \oplus y) \land c_{in}) \lor (x \land y))$ to CNF. We see that we need $32$ extra variables and $32 \times 14 = 448$ clauses to encode a $32$-bit adder circuit using this method. This is almost certainly better than the circuit encoding, which requires both more variables and more clauses.
\end{document}
```

(Looking at the [`mathdesign` documentation](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/fonts/mathdesign/mathdesign-doc.pdf), I think that in a perfect world you would only need to include `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` to get all the fonts loaded correctly. I assume that `mathdesign` is just making some small mistake in its handling of Charter, and that you can undo this mistake by re-loading the Charter package afterwards.)

Comment: It works here, but I notice that the text is generally broken differently. So is the problem truly fixed by this, or is it just fixed because something else changed the line breaking and released some of the "pressure" on the F and the . to go close together?

Comment: @Vegard It looks to me that the only reason the text is broken differently in your example is that there is now slightly more space between the `F` and `.` I do not think the space between these two characters has much stretch, because you can try changing it to `to extra space CNF.`, for example, and the kerning problem remains, unless you switch the package load order.