# charter and siunitx: either the kerning is bad, or the micro doesn't follow the surrounding text shape. What can I do?

Tags: siunitx, kerning, mathdesign

I'm using Charter (with the `mathdesign` package) for my main text font. 
As mathdesign isn't doing a good job at kerning (see "NOP." and "DEF." in MWE), I'm additionally loading the `charter` package as suggested in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79885/using-the-charter-font-f-followed-by-a-full-stop-looks-like-an-e-what-should-i).

In addition, I have quite a few units with \micro prefixes in the text. I would like my numbers and units to be in the same shape as the surrounding text. However, when loading the `charter` package in addition to `mathdesign`, the mu changes.

What can I do?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign} 
%\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[detect-all=true]{siunitx} 

\begin{document}
Testing the kerning with two examples: NOP. DEF.

Testing the ``micro'': \SI{1}{\micro\metre} 

\textit{in italic text: \SI{1}{\micro\metre}}

\end{document}
```

Example 1: bad kerning, nice detection of surroundings in siunitx

[image: Example 1, bad kerning, nice detection of surroundings in siunitx]

Example 2: better kerning, no detection of surroundings in siunitx

[image: Example 2, better kerning, no detection of surroundings in siunitx]

Comment: Units are symbols and shouldn't change shape according to the context.

Comment: Okay, I can accept that units shouldn't change shape (though 'siunitx' specifically has an option for this), but I find it distracting if the mu is italic and the and the m is not (and in example 2 the mu also doesn't match the m in x-height...)

Comment: My comment was only about the appearance of the symbols; I agree that the mu should be upright.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The normal Charter font (font family `bch`, which you load with the `charter` package) does not include an upright `\textmu` (this is the name of the µ in text mode). Also, it doesn't contain an Ω at all, which would therefore be selected from Computer Modern Roman. But you can access the glyphs provided by the `mathdesign` package with `\fontfamily{mdbch}\textmu` and `\textohm`. In math mode, on the other hand, you would always want the upright versions, which `mathdesign` makes available as `\muup` and `\Omegaup`.

So the following should do what you want, and it will also fix the situation if you choose to follow the advice to always set units upright:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[detect-all=true]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
        math-micro=\muup,
        math-ohm  =\Omegaup,
        text-micro={\fontfamily{mdbch}\textmu},
        text-ohm  ={\fontfamily{mdbch}\textohm}
}
\begin{document}
Testing the kerning with two examples: NOP. DEF.

With font switch: \SI{1}{\micro\metre}, \SI{1}{\ohm},
\textit{in italic text: \SI{1}{\micro\metre}, \SI{1}{\ohm}}

In math mode: $\SI{1}{\micro\metre}, \SI{1}{\ohm}$,
\textit{in italic math: $\SI{1}{\micro\metre}, \SI{1}{\ohm}$}

\sisetup{detect-all=false}
Always upright: \SI{1}{\micro\metre}, \SI{1}{\ohm},
\textit{in italic text: \SI{1}{\micro\metre}, \SI{1}{\ohm}}

In math mode: $\SI{1}{\micro\metre}, \SI{1}{\ohm}$,
\textit{in italic math: $\SI{1}{\micro\metre}, \SI{1}{\ohm}$}
\end{document}
```

[image: charter mu & Omega]

Comment: This works as desired. However - again ignoring the question of whether units should change shape - is there a way to get the '\Omega' of the unit '\ohm' to change shape as well? 'mathdesign' does not provide a '\textOmega' similar to '\textmu' but has both an '\Omegaup' and '\Omegait' symbol (for math mode). '\sisetup{text-ohm=\ensuremath{\Omega}}' obviously does not work... I'll probably use the convention of upright units even in italic text now, but would still like to know for the sake of completeness...

Comment: @TestTube The command is `\textohm`, see updated answer.

Comment: I've looked at the 'mathdesign' documentation a couple of times today, but somehow managed to always overlook this... Thanks!