# Appearance of Greek µ with siunitx is regular font with Gentium but italic with XCharter – why?

Tags: fonts, siunitx

I'm trying to select a serif font for my thesis, and have narrowed down my choices to two (probably!) – Gentium and XCharter. I like both, but the latter puts the Greek µ for 'micro' in italics when using macros from the `siunitx` package – which I don't like. The only difference between the two preambles is the font loaded (MWE shown with `gentium` loaded and `XCharter` commented out; just reverse these to see the difference).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[greek, UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gentium}
% \usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[libertine,bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}

\sisetup{detect-all}      % Uses current font for units ({siunitx})
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} 

\begin{document}
{\textbf{Gentium}} \\
% {\textbf{XCharter}} \\
Homogenate was drawn off into a \SI{2}{\ml} tube, and \SI{400}{\ul} chloroform was added to it.
\end{document}
```

Why does XCharter behave differently, and is there a workaround?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you escape all the brackets in your preamble?

Comment: Er, don't understand the question! What do you mean by 'escape all the brackets'?

Comment: He refers to `\[..\]`.

Comment: Ah, I do now see that strange characters have appeared before and after my code! Not sure what happened there, it was a simple copy and past from my .tex file. Anyway, duly edited – thanks @Sverre for pointing it out.

Comment: I'm not sure it's in italics, it's the design of the available symbol.

Comment: Even textcomp's \textmu is giving italic mu with XCharter.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206837/changing-mu-in-siunitx/206870?noredirect=1#comment482385_206870

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[greek, UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{gentium}
 \usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[libertine,bigdelims,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}

\sisetup{detect-all}      % Uses current font for units ({siunitx})
\sisetup{
        math-micro={\muup}, 
        text-micro={\fontfamily{mdbch}\textmu},
}


\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} 

\begin{document}


 {\textbf{XCharter}} \\
Homogenate was drawn off into a \SI{2}{\ml} tube, and \SI{400}{\micro \litre} chloroform was added to it.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Care to add some explanation?

Comment: My penultimate comment contains the necessary information and adding them again -- would be quite repetitive wouldn't it?

Comment: I think it wouldn't.

Comment: I think that's a good explanation: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135125/25683

Comment: But you could also load the upmu form the upgreek-package, \usepackage{upgreek}            \sisetup{
        text-micro={$\upmu$},
}